# Facebook Connect login dialog not working

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am using Facebook Connect for iPhone and following the [official instructions](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). I use the following code to display the login dialog:

```
FBLoginDialog* dialog = [[[FBLoginDialog alloc] initWithSession:session] autorelease];
[dialog show];
```

(Note that the results are the same when I go with the FBLoginButton approach instead of showing the dialog directly.)

The dialog pops up as expected, but as you see in the screenshot below, it is way too large and looks like the full Facebook homepage. I can pan the dialog to reveal the login button, but once I log in it proceeds to show the regular Facebook page inside the dialog. It never calls my `session:didLogin` callback.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20091115-t24w7p5gpa6iqgehjdc4f1awfs.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20091115-t24w7p5gpa6iqgehjdc4f1awfs.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out... I was initializing the `FBSession` inside my app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method. I then triggered the Facebook login code in my view controller's `viewDidAppear`.

However, `applicationDidFinishLaunching` looked like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.session = [FBSession sessionForApplication:FB_API_KEY secret:FB_APP_SECRET delegate:self];
}
```

This means that I was showing the window before I was initializing the `FBSession`, and apparently a nil session leads to the behavior I described above. After changing `applicationDidFinishLaunching` to create the `FBSession` first, everything now works as expected. Doh... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mirko, I had the exact same problem but reached via a different implementation. Here are the facts:

- The problem was the same on the simulator and on a physical device. The wrong user agent is a red herring.
- Before displaying the dialog (either directly via FBLoginDialog or using the FBLoginButton), you must have established your session (either via "[[FBSession sessionForApplication:kApiKey secret:kApiSecret delegate:self] retain];" or the proxy method). Or calling [session resume] on an already existing session.
- The state of the session object before displaying the dialog has no effect. As long as I have called the above methods to establish my session, I can do "session = nil" or "[session logout]", and I still get the correct dialog. If I do not establish my session first, I get the wrong full homepage effect.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. So it's not the actual FBSession object that's passed into FBLoginDialog that matters, but whether any of the methods that establish a session have been called. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the FaceBook API library, but did you try changing `dialog.frame` before sending the `show` message?

Comment: Changing the dialog's frame has no effect. Also note that when using the FBLoginButton approach, this would not even be an option, as this internally pops up the dialog.

The dialog itself has the correct size. It's just that it's contents (presumably a web view) are wrong.

Comment: Also, it's not just the size of the login dialog, but the behavior as well. It's like it simply displays a regular Facebook site instead of the expected login dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this on a device? What OS are you building against? I'm using an almost identical call with no problems (-init, vs. initWithSession). Also, I'm assuming you have a window and view architecture already set up behind this, correct?

Comment: Yes, I had a window and view already set up (using the view based app template). I tried building against 3.0 and 3.1.2, both simulator and actual device. But see my answer. It turns out I hadn't initialized the FBSession by the time I was displaying the login dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I only had this problem, only the device, not on the simulator.  Apparently the Facebook page is using the device's user agent to render the correct page.  If you wanted to, you should be able to change that by adding a User Agent header to the http calls FB Connect's Web View is making.

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior on both the device and the simulator. And I'm using Facebook Connect for iPhone, which doesn't seem to give me access to underlying HTTP headers such as the User Agent.

Comment: I just pulled up my code and saw that I wrote a workaround for the same problem.  Basically the issue is Facebook connect wants you to put a FBLoginButton in your app, which then opens up the Login Dialog.  My workaround is posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I just pulled up my code and saw that I wrote a workaround for the same problem. Basically the issue is Facebook connect wants you to put a FBLoginButton in your app, which then opens up the Login Dialog. In order to display the dialog without the button I did this:

```
faceBookSession = [FBSession sessionForApplication:kFacebookAPIKey secret:kFaceBookAPISeceret delegate:self];
    if (![faceBookSession resume]) {
        FBLoginButton *button = [[FBLoginButton alloc] init];
        [button performSelector:@selector(touchUpInside)];
        [button release];
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't need this workaround. As per my own answer above as well as "unknown (google)"'s answer, the only thing you need to ensure is to call one of the methods to create a FBSession before you attempt to display the login dialog. Once you do this, you can either display the FBLoginDialog directly (using the code from my original question) or use an FBLoginButton. There's no need for you to create a dummy button and simulate clicking on it.